# How to fix the Postgrest issue while fetching records

Tags: postgrest

I am using PostgRest 8.0.0 and Postgres DB v14. I am facing the following error for selection of rows in a table.
http://localhost:3000/table

error:

```
{
    "hint": null,
    "message": "invalid configuration parameter name \"request.header.user-agent\"",
    "code": "42602",
    "details": "Custom parameter names must be two or more simple identifiers separated by dots."
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit: You should use [PostgREST 9](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/releases/v9.0.0.html) with postgresql >= 14

PostgREST 8.0.0 is incompatible with postgres 14, see https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/issues/1857.

This will be fixed in a new release. For now, you can use the latest binary which contains a fix for postgres 14. You can download it [here](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/actions/runs/1334266540)(bottom of the page).